# How to make a JLabel's setText a safe method

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

In swing I made a JLabel (for a chronometer). I am using a thread that loops and sleeps every second, so every second I write the seconds.

Code:

```
new thread(){
   public void run(){
   int i=0;
   while(true){ 
    try{
      sleep(1000);
       }catch(Exception e){}
       i++;
       jlabel1.settext(i);
    }
   }
}.start();
```

Then I use another thread for a moving panel jpanel1

```
 new thread(){
   public void run(){
   while(true){ 
    try{
      sleep(100);
       }catch(Exception e){}
       j+=15;
       j=j%400;
       jpanel1.setLocation(j,50);
    }
   }
}.start();
```

How do I fix this code because when the `setText()` of the label is done for every second the panel acts weirdly (he starts from the origin then he go back to it current point)
all my research says that Java's swing and awt are not a safe methods when it comes to paint components.

Can someone help me fix this?

Comment: Multithreading and background tasks are not your only problem. First of all I can't see where you declare j but i assume you declare it as an int somewhere above your thread. But your variable j will always be 0.`j = 15; 15%400 = 0;`

Comment: hi sorry i only used a summery code but if you wanna all the code there is no problem, all i wanted is to give an idea about my problem @dehlen

Comment: and 15%400=15 (y) ^_^

Comment: Sorry for my language. English is my third language ... Really sorry I m doing my best to improve.
@Mr.Polywhirl

Comment: Yeah of course its 15 i meant it :D anyway it is part of the weird behaviour he had. Because the jpanel goes to the right (x position 15,30,45) and then it comes to some value over 400) Lets say 405 and the modulo operation will throw it back to x Position = 5

Comment: yes but what you will see is this list of position knowing from the start that X is on 0
(time,X) (100,15) (200,30) (300,45) ... (900,135) (1000,0) (1100,165) ... (2000,0) (2100,315)
try a quick project you will see this behaviour @dehlen

Comment: No it won't in your example, the y parameter won't change at all since you set it to 50. Only the x Parameter will change and the parameter will always be between 0 and 399

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *all my researchs says that java swing and awt are not a safe methods when it comes to paint compenents*

And those are right, Swing components must be created and updated in the [Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html). See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) tutorial for further details.

What is happening here is that Swing components (both, label and panel) are being updated *outside* the EDT. To fix this issue and given your requirement is to make a chronometer, the most useful tool is [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) (link to tutorial) that will perform repetitive tasks at a given period of time and it's safe to do Swing components update within the `actionPerformed()` implementation, because those run in the EDT.

For example:

```
Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {

     int i = 0;

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        i++;
        label.setText(String.valueOf(i));
    }
};

timer.setRepeats(true); // it will be repeated every 1 sec.
timer.start();
```